# Bitcoin - Green mining

Tags: energy-consumption

I would like to know whether any work known to bitcoin community, related to 'green mining'. As power consumption is main cost factor in mining, alternate energy sources like, solar / wind powered rigs could also be possible. Thanks.

Comment: Was. Power was the main cost factor in **GPU** mining.  It no longer is with today's FGPA mining hardware, and is even less of a factor with the ASIC hardware so many are patiently waiting on.

Comment: This question could be viable with some edits. As it stands, it's soliciting a laundry list of sources, but if it were rephrased properly it could solicit a single answer and I'd consider re-opening it.

Answer (score 2):

One attempt, .... Diablo Mining Company didn't go so well.

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=77469

So far, the most profitable mining has been in nations whose taxpayers provide subsidized electricity.  Essentially, it is like a form of welfare for Bitcoin mining entrepreneurs.

ASICs have removed that advantage though so it never got to be that big of a deal.